# Template driven validations need to work in cancel button

Tags: forms, validation, angular6

In a form I have two buttons `save` and `cancel`.  In the save button I have done validations for input and kendo date picker but the problem is
cancel button purpose is clear the input values.while clear the values automatically validation messages are showing.

How can I prevent the validations for cancel button in angular 6

```
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && saveFilter()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="formNew">
        <label for="name">Custom Filter Name:</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filtername" name="filter" #filter="ngModel" placeholder="Filter name" maxlength="50" [ngClass]="{ 'custom-filtername': f.submitted && !filter.dirty}" required />
    </div>
    <kendo-datepicker class="kendoCalendarPickerBox" [ngClass]="{'custom-datepciker':f.submitted &&!isdatepicker.dirty &&!isChecked}" [(ngModel)]= "Datevalue" required></kendo-datepicker>
    <div class="footer">
        <span class="foot_left">
            <button type="button" class="btn blueBtn lftBtn" (click)="FilterAction('Delete')">Delete</button>
        </span>
        <span class="foot_right">
            <button class="btn blueBtn"> {{saveButtonName}}</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btnDefault" (click)="FilterAction('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your code as a reproducible example.

Comment: <form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && saveFilter()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<div class="formNew">
    <label for="name">Custom Filter Name:</label>
    <input type="text" 
    [(ngModel)]="filtername"
    name="filter"
    #filter="ngModel" 
    placeholder="Filter name"
    maxlength="50"
    [ngClass]="{ 'custom-filtername': f.submitted && !filter.dirty}"
      required />
  </div>
<kendo-datepicker class="kendoCalendarPickerBox"
 [ngClass]="{'custom-datepciker':f.submitted &&!isdatepicker.dirty &&!isChecked}"
      [(ngModel)]= "Datevalue" required>
    </kendo-datepicker>

Comment: <div class="footer">
    <span class="foot_left">
      <button type="button" class="btn blueBtn lftBtn" (click)="FilterAction('Delete')">Delete</button>
    </span>
    <span class="foot_right">
        <button class="btn blueBtn"> {{saveButtonName}}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btnDefault" (click)="FilterAction('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </form>

Comment: Please see the  source code

Comment: Please put your code into the question body and format it as a code block.